# (Servlet) Request to display the name of the user.... Error with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, servlets

i am facing problem while running example which shows how a parameter is passed to a servlet in request object from html page.

My index.html contails-

```
   <form action="welcome" method="get">  
Enter your name<input type="text" name="name"><br>  
<input type="submit" value="login">  
    </form>
```

my .xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>FirstServlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>MyServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>check</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/check</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

and .java

```
    package cmctest;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
       response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {

            String user=request.getParameter("user");
            out.println("<h2> Welcome "+user+"</h2>");
        } finally {            
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

when i am running this on server i am getting error,
please help me out to resolve this problem.

error image here
(remove dot please ~ i am new here and running low with rep >.< )

stack.imgur.com/iN85H[dot]jpg

i have even tried to run downloaded example in/for eclipse but still same error

Comment: Those are all INFO outputs, not ERROR outputs. What's not working that should be working?

Comment: What is the url you are using?

Comment: What is the url you are using to access the servlet. Is it http://localhost:8080/check ?. And if this is not the url you are using to access the servlet, then the mapping is wrong. In the form you are saying action="welcome". check whether this works <url-pattern>/welcome</url-pattern>. And also i see that the package name is missing in the <servlet-class></servlet-class> tag. Your Servlet is in package cmtest. So it should be<servlet-class>cmtest.MyServlet</servlet-class>. It should be fully qualified name.